# My electric guitar not making sound

Tags: guitar

I'm a beginner electric guitar player. I bought LTD EC 10 yesterday. It was going well until today. When I plug to my amp and hold strings or play it doesn't make sound but when I keep it open noise is coming from amp…… I'm using Line 6 spider iv. Amp and cable is good I've checked it with acoustic. Can anyone help me? What might be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Could be a lot of different things. Let's make a check list:

- The obvious first: are all the volume knobs fully open?
- If the guitar is active (i.e. with a battery-powered pre-amp), did you perhaps run out of battery?
- In some (most?) active guitars, the pre-amp is automatically turned on when the jack is plugged in the guitar. That means, whenever the jack is in, the battery is being used. If you leave the guitar with the jack in for a day or more, it could use up all the battery.
- Some guitars can switch between active and passive mode by pressing a volume knob (as if it were a button, press it toward the body and it will toggle on and off). Perhaps if the battery is drained, you can switch to passive mode and still play.

Comment: Might add making sure the volume knob, tone control, and pickup selector are set correctly.

Comment: As a potential source of the "more noise when released": my (older) line 6 amp had an aggressive noise cut filter enabled by default on all channels and presets, so perhaps when the OP is muting the strings, there is less noise and when they let go, the noise rises above the noise filter cutoff point. On my amp, this is a hidden setting so the OP may need to refer to the manual to disable the noise filter.